# Using FetchedResultsController to Keep UITableView Up to Date?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've started a small tech demo project just to get a feel for core Data. I want a table view loaded up that keeps up to date with the data stored using core data.

I think I've implemented the data model and saving the notes correctly in this. However it's not updating on the table. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, perhaps I haven't linked something up correctly or something?

I've checked the persistent store on my file system and the note I created is in there so I know the core data is writing to file OK.

Any help would be appreciated. I've uploaded the project as a zip to avoid pasting the whole class here. The delegate and data source of the table is set to the view controller in my storyboard too.

The project is at: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12457690/cdtest.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there are a several problems:

- You have not implemented any of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods.
  How do you expect the table view to update automatically?
- In your `setManagedObjectContext:` method, you create a fetched results controller, but don't set the delegate.
- Your `performFetch` method is never called. Even if it were called, it would not call
  `performFetch:` on the fetched results controller because no predicate has been set (why this restriction?).
- In your `deleteNote:` method, you should just delete the managed object. Updating the
  table view accordingly is done by the fetched results controller (if implemented correctly).

Perhaps start by implementing the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods (there is
sample code in the documentation of that protocol). Then set breakpoints in your code
and check if the delegate of the fetched results controller is set, and check if
the initial `performFetch:` is called.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the delete method, implemented the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods and went a new way about getting a managedObjectContext object by creating a static DocumentHandler class and getting an instance of managedObjectContext.